# how much time it takes to start a separate core task procedure on windows?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

lets say that I have a procedure which takes a one 
millisecond to run and finish. I want to start it up
on a sperate core on windows - how many time it takes
to start such routine on a sperate thread - is this 
delay 0.001 ms ? 0.1 ms, ? 1 ms ? How long doeas it 
take

Comment: IMO it totally depends on the hardware you are running on and the system load. You should do measurements by yourself on the same hardware that gave you the processing time of your procedure, this way you will have a more or less reliable information if it worth it to run it on a separate thread.

Comment: cannot measure this those days - maybe someone tested it ? I want orientational value (assume that you have a free core/cores to use with no heavy load)

Comment: Not so long ago I answered a question where someone was asking why OpenMP had worse time than serial version of program. Problem was the task x 10K iteratons took 1.5s. Which is 0.15ms per task execution he tried to parallelize. OpenMP version was abt 5x slower. This is a hint how long it take in invoke a parallel region. So my very general guess would be around 0.1 to 1ms in modern PC/OS. IMO it almost utter nonsense in putting something that take 1ms into separate thread. If you have lots of such jobs expect the overhead to be 0.1 to 10 of the actual time needed.

Comment: 1 ms task it is not so total nonsense IMO but it is short task. When writing games you have to paralelise each frame calculations and this frame time is about 1 to 30 ms so this knowledge how delay it takes to run such millisekond task would be interesting to me

Comment: I think maybe it is related to windows scheduler time-resolution (and it depends for windows timer resolution which could be set to 0.5 or 15 ms AFAIK (but not sure) plus some running new thread overhead (which I do not know how much it takes) Do not know details I HOPE it is closer to 0.1 ms - 1 ms not to 10 - 100 ms :/

Comment: It also depends on whether the thread that is going to run the task already exists or not.  Signaling a thread that already exists is considerably faster, (and safer), than creating one 'on demand'. Typically, if there is a core free, kernel signaling latency, (ie, signaling an event, or semaphore), is 2-20 us on my box. So, threading off a 1ms task is perfectly reasonable, as long as the thread already exists.

Comment: @grungefightr - time resoultion doesn't matter in the general case, where there is a core free and/or a lower-priority thread that can be preempted.  By the time 'CreateThread()' API returns, the new thread will be, at least, ready. It may well be running. It also may have preempted the caller and already run until termination.

Comment: It further depends on whether other threads are being created or stopped or DLLs are being loaded, since all these are serialized by the loader lock. A thread could possibly take _half a second_ before it is created. That's why you don't create threads when you need them, too. You create them when your program starts. Thus, the entire question of how long it takes doesn't arise.

Comment: Yeah - what @Damon says. Also, if a thread has been non-running for a long time on a busy system, it may get its code and/or stack paged out.  All sorts of cruft.  Still gonna be piles faster to have a thread available when you need one, either on a pool, or as app-lifetime threads.

Comment: allrite then it is a task how delay one get when there is need to fire some milisecond task on other free core ? -is it such low as 2-20 microseconds  as martin james stated in every case or it debends, how it is in usual (windows programming)

Comment: you know and when this core will do its millisecond task how much deley it will take to make it execute another task - I want to know how this "between task" delay is so I could find least resonable granularity of raning tasks on free core -m it is not instant and I think it may be not so fast than 20 microsekond delay

Comment: @grungefightr - I can only go on my past experience.  I have done comparitive timings on producer-consumer queue classes.  If everything is 'warmed up' ie. the signaled thread exists, has run recently, and has a core free, then 2-20 us is the signaling latency using kernel signaling. If the situation is any more complex - a DLL needs loading, the box is very busy, a process-switch is required, a thread running on another core has to be preempted or any of the other stuff, (see Damon), then there will be extra delays.

Comment: Yet in another words it is : the local core function call is instant, how cycles do it take the external-core function call (aind its ret)

Comment: @martin james - ok if it is only 2-20 mikrosekonds to run function on 'external' core it seem to be quite good - though of course it could be still better ; )

Comment: @grungefightr it depends!  Threads cannot be called or returned from, only signaled.  Inter-thread signaling is not going to be as cheap as a call/return on the same thread.  As Damon correctly says, try very hard to not create a thread on-demand and then wait for it to terminate.  That is probably the slowest possible mechanism for running your code/data on another thread. If you want your data processed quickly by another thread, make sure you have one available beforehand.

Comment: Alrrite -if you say 'signaled' how much delay there it is when you send a signal 'start doing this' then do and then receive signal 'it is done' With no delay all such time would be task time, in real it is task time with some delay (assume that the task is simple calculattions in for loop) - how 'scale' this delay is (often) 20 mikroseconds , more ? That answer I am searching for, if it depends I would like to see some examples (cannot measure it myself those days - other way I would try to measure it by myself)